# server side pagination in jquery data table and custom property

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331855/jQuery-DataTables-Advanced-Filtering-in-ASP-NET-MV) for implementing jquery data table with server side pagination.

My question is: 
How can I add custom property inside `jQueryDataTableParamModel` in order to send this property to the controller from the view.

Note: it doesnt has to be inside `jQueryDataTableParamModel` class, point is to deliver `CompanyId` to the controller each time when `jQueryDataTableParam` is received as param in the controller action.

```
public class jQueryDataTableParamModel 
{
    ...
    public int CompanyId{ get; set; }
}
```

controller action

```
public ActionResult GetData(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
{
    ...
}
```

update:

```
var oTable = $('#dataTables-table').dataTable({                
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "/Home/Data",
                "bProcessing": true,
                "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {                   
                    aoData.push({ "name": "CompanyID", "value": 555 });
                },
                "aoColumns": [
                                {
                                    "sName": "Id",
                                    "bSearchable": false,
                                    "bSortable": false                                    
                                },
                                { "sName": "DATA1" },
                                { "sName": "DATA2" },
                                { "sName": "DATA3" }

                ]
            });
```

Comment: Do you refresh table like this `oTable.ajax.reload()`? And I am not sure about "sAjaxSource"

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I've recently worked with JQuery DataTables and Pagination. Try this:

```
    public ActionResult GroupsDetailAjaxHandler(JQueryDataTableParamModel param, int? CompanyID)
    {

        var _table = _repo.GetData(CompanyID ?? 0);

        return Json(new
        {
            aaData = from emp in _table
                     select new[] {  emp.item1,emp.item3,emp.item3 }

        },
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Jquery code

```
    var oGroupsDetail = $('#GroupsDetail').DataTable({
        "ajax": "/Home/GroupsDetailAjaxHandler",
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "CompanyID", "value": yourCompanyIDvariable });
        }


    });
```

Comment: Thank you for a response. Are you sure that this work in mvc5? Initialization of jquery data table failed when using fnServerParams.

Comment: I think it doesnt depends on mvc version. Maybe your problem is in version of jquery or datatable. Or may be you initialize that with dataTable instead of DataTable()

Comment: This example from mvc4 project, jquery-1.11.1 and DataTables 1.10.4

Comment: no, problem was that I'm not set int parameter as nullable. Now I'm able to initalize script and data table but CompanyId is always null inside controller action (even when I hardcode this value in the view). Any idea?

Comment: check carefully where you are initializing a variable or setting the value. It's tough to help you blindly. In my project I initialize `var CompanyID = null;` At the right moment I set the value to this variable and push it `aoData.push({ "name": "CompanyID", "value": CompanyID });`

Comment: I updated question, here's how I assign CompanyID (it's always null in the controller).